# In optim(): Error in par[1] : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable - optim() for linear regression with constraints

Tags: r, optimization, linear-regression

I am trying to write a function that takes a data frame with a dependent variable in column 1 and n independent variables in column 2 to n+1 to fit a linear model between y~x1+..xn+1, subject to the constraint that all coefficients of x1 to xn are 0 or above.

To do so, I started using optim and some functions to produce a generic text formula to minimize RSS and which I evaluate as code in the optimizer. However, my approach returns the following error:

```
Error in par[1] : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
```

Essentially, my idea of using optim to do OLS with a constraints is based on the following example: https://magesblog.com/post/2013-03-12-how-to-use-optim-in-r/

Here are the functions (incl. sample data)

```
set.seed(1000)
#Function to produce n vectors + one y vector with 5000 observation (approx 20 business years):    
sampler <- function(n){
   df <- data.frame(y=sample(-100:100,5000, replace=TRUE))
   for (i in (1:n+1)){
    df[,i] <- sample(-100:100,5000,replace=TRUE)
   }
   df
}

#Function to produce formula for constrained optimization
formfun <- function(n) {
  part <- ""
  parts <- c("sum((")
  for (i in (1:n)){
    part[i]<- paste0("par[",i,"] * df[",i+1,"] + ",sep="")
    parts <- append(parts,part[i])
   }
   parts <- paste0(append(parts,"-df[1])^2)"),sep="")
   parts
}

#Function to evaluate formula
min.RSS <- function(par,data,form) {
  eval(parse(text=paste0(form)))
}
```

Plugging in n:

```
 n=5
 df <- sampler(n)
 formula <- formfun(n)
 min.RSS(par,data=df,form=formula)
```

Finally, giving formula with all params into the optimizer:

```
result <- optim(par = c(rep(1,n)),min.RSS(par, data=df, form=formula),  method = c("L-BFGS-B"), lower = 0.00, upper = 10000)
```

This unfortunately gives:

```
Error in par[1] : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
```

Any help as to why this happens is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You should pass the name of the function to be optimized without any arguments. Pass the `data=df` and `form=formula` as arguments to `optim`.

Comment: Very clean - works like a charm! I was about to give up on it! Thank you so much!

Comment: either this should be closed as "due to a typographical error" or someone (OP or @Bhas) should construct an answer based on these comments ...